# Ethers js set noonce when using contract object

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

I use `ethers` to interact with solidity contract. I would like to execute multiple transactions at the same time. To do that I know I have to define `noonce` that would be +1 for each next transaction. I know how to do that when I do

```
await signer.sendTransaction()
```

but how can I execute multiple transactions with custom `noonce` when I create `Contract` object and execute function on it? I tried

```
contract.methodName(methodParams, {
      gasLimit: gasLimit,
      gasPrice,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther(
        "0.01"
      ),
      noonce: nextNoonce
    })
```

but it doesn't work and I get error `cannot override "noonce"`. How can I define it here?

Comment: I hope you were referring to the "nonce"  - https://help.myetherwallet.com/en/articles/5461509-what-is-a-nonce

Answer (score 2):

To get new nonce every time use getNonce() function

```js
  const nonce = await wallet.getNonce();
```

Complete Code

```js
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
async function main() {
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545');

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    'Your private key here',
    provider
  );

 
  const nonce = await wallet.getNonce();
  const txn = {
    nonce,
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    to: null,
    value: 0,
    data: '0xpaste binary here',
    chainId: 1337, //Change this chain Id, I am using Ganache
  };
  const sentTxnResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(txn);
  console.log(sentTxnResponse);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Note : I am using **ethers version 6.2.3**

Answer (score 0):

To set the nonce value using [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/) you can fetch it through the [provider](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/) as below:

To read more about [nonce](https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-is-nonce/).

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const { ethereum } = window;
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
const signer = provider?.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    CONTRACT_ABI,
    signer
);
const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(contract.address);
const tx = await contract.methodName(param1, param2, {
                    gasLimit:gasLimit,
                    gasPrice:gasPrice,
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
                    nonce:nonce,
                });
```

**Step 2: Reset your Metamask account.**

Sometimes the issue is with your metamask account and needs to be reset to get the correct customer nonce value.

To reset your account:

Click Metamask Icon > Advanced Setting > Reset Account

[image]